# If $r$ is the remainder of dividing the number $17*2^{635}$ by $33$, then $8$ divides $r$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, divisibility

How can I prove the statement below?

$r\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:  $ 0\leq r\leq 32$

If *r* is the remainder of dividing the number $17*2^{635}$ by *33*, then *8* divides r

Comment: Hint: simplify your exponent with $2^5 =32=-1$ mod $33$.

Comment: What does "8 divides $r$" really mean when every integer is congruent with a multiple of 8 modulo 33?

Comment: @OscarLanzi: The question is unambiguous. The OP explicitly states that $0\le r\le 32$.

Comment: Still awkward to me.  I would have asked to find the remainder/residue explicitly instead.

Comment: I suspect the OP is assuming that finding the exact value of $r$ is very difficult or maybe even not possible and assumes we can only find a few properties of it. In actuality it is very easy to find that $r =16$.  Exactly.

Comment: If you do not know any number theory:  $2^5=32=33-1$. $17= 33-16$. so $17*2^{635}=(33-16)(33-1)^{127}$. If we expand that out into a very long sum, every term except the very last one will be a multiple of $33$.  The only term that isn't a multiple of $33$ is the last one;$(-16)\cdot(-1)= +16$.  So the remainder when you divide by $33$ will be $16$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can calculate $r$ explicity.

Notice that $2^a\bmod 33$ is periodic with period $lcm(11-1,3-1)=10$.

Hence we need only calculate $2^5\bmod 33$ which is $-1$. So $r$ is $-17\equiv 16$, and $8$ divides $16$

Comment: I suppose you meant $r$ is $16\equiv-17$, and $8$ divides $\color{red}16$

Comment: Indeed, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still don't understand how *r = -1* turns into *r = 16*

Comment: @Joaozzx2:  $r\equiv17\times2^5\equiv17\times-1\equiv-17\equiv16\bmod33$

Answer (score 2):

$\!\!\bmod \color{#c00}{2^{\large 5}\!+1}\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{2^{\large 5}\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, 17(\color{#c00}{2^{\large 5}})^{\large 127}\!\equiv 17(\color{#c00}{-1})^{\large 127}\!\equiv -17\equiv 16\,$ via [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

Comment: Where did $73$ come from?  Did you read $365$ instead of $635$ in OP?

Comment: @J.W.T By misreading the exponent as 365 (but its the same for any odd multiple of $5)\ $ But now made consistent with the OP.

Comment: This is a special case of [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242). See the "Linked" questions there for many worked examples (including examples where CRT is used, as is implicitly done in Jorge's answer).